# inclusion-exclusion principle

Tags: inclusion-exclusion, sumset

I don't have any way to see if I have done this in a correct way(no answers in my book). Did I do it right?

**Question:** "*How many eight-bit strings either begin 100 or have the fourth bit 1 or both?*"

My calculations:
X - contains the strings that begins with 100
Y - contains the strings that has the fourth position set to 1

As I understand the question, this is how the bit string looks like: $[?????100]$. If it begins with 100.

**The size of $|X|$:**

Since we already have 3 bits already set, 100, that means we only have 5 bits that can change in value which gives us 32 combinations.

$|X| = 32$

**The size of $|Y|$:** Now we have 6 bits to work with. $2^7=128$

$|Y| = 128$

**Combined $|X|∩|Y|$**:Half of all bit strings contain the 1 bit on the fourth position. Which must mean half of the bit strings in X contain 1 on position 4. So I remove them, to not get repititon, now $|X|$ = 16

So $|X|U|Y|$ = 144

There are 144 bit string that either starts with 100 or has bit 1 on the fourth position.

Am I correct?

Comment: This looks exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

As confirmation, and to demonstrate a useful technique:

You are trying to count strings that meet a complex set of requirements.  Instead, look at the complementary problem;  in this case:  *How many strings fail the requirements?*

There are $256$ eight-bit strings.

There are eight possible leading three-bit strings;  seven of them (all but $100$) fail being the required leading string, and are *candidates* for elimination from the counted group.
Considering these candidates, half of them will have the fourth bit $0$ and, having failed both qualifications, will not be part of the group to be counted:

So the number *not* counted:$$N_{not}=256 \times \frac78 \times \frac12=112$$So the number *counted* : $$N_{Count}=256-112=144$$